# Solr fatal error when trying to commit files

Tags: solr, lucene

I was able to post files to Solr for indexing just fine until I started getting this error suddenly:

> SimplePostTool: FATAL: Solr returned an error #500 Permission denied  java.io.IOException: Permission denied  at
>   java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:900)  at
>   org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSLock.obtain(SimpleFSLockFactory.java:128)
>   at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:72)  at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:1098)  at
>   org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.(SolrIndexWriter.java:84)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.createMainIndexWriter(UpdateHandler.java:101)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.openWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:115)
>   at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:157)
>   at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:79)  at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>   at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)  at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450) 
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)

Anyone know what all this means and/or how to fix it?

Command I'm using to commit files:

```
java -jar post.jar foo.xml
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error means that Solr doesn't have write access to its index directory.

Comment: so would changing the permissions of that index dir (chmod 777) solve the issue? If so where is it located, or at least how can I find out where it's located in my installation?

Comment: To see it, go to http://${host}:${port}/solr/${core}/admin/stats.jsp and look for `readerDir`. This will tell you the directory implementation as well as where the index is stored. `chmod -R 777` would work but your sys admins might not be happy with it :)

Comment: Thanks so much jpountz, worked beautifully. I'm on a localhost dev machine so I'm not worried about permission related security issues yet (until my app is launched to prod at least).